# ngResource PUT action isn't executed

Tags: angularjs, rest, ngresource

I have created the following Controller

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DoneController', Done);

    Done.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Preference'];

    function Done($scope, $stateParams, Preference) {
      // PUT
      Preference.savePreference({
        action: 'purchased',
        model: $stateParams.model
      });
    }
}());
```

which call the following service

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Preference', PreferenceService);

    PreferenceService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function PreferenceService($resource) {
      return $resource("http://localhost:8000/preferences",
        null,
        {
          savePreference: { method: 'PUT' }
        });
    }
}());
```

The server expect the following request

`http://localhost:8000/preferences?action=puchased&model=id`

the problem is that it isn't executed and I don't know why. Have you any idea? the server is up.

Comment: If I replace PUT with GET then it work but with PUT nothing happen

Comment: Is it that nothing happens on the server side or that the method isn't called on the client side (any call/response in browser's network tab)?